# PHP implode array value without using foreach

Tags: php

I have an array in this format

```
Array
(
 [0] => 96
 [1] => 97
 [2] => 98
 [3] => 99
 [4] => 100
)
```

and I want the output to become like this "96,97,98,99,100" without using foreach.
Do you have any idea what php function I should use?

-- UPDATE --

```
for($count = 0; $count < $total_test_name ; $count++)
{
 $test_name_array = $this->input->post('item_description',true);
 ref_value_array  = $this->input->post('reference_value',true);

 $data_item_array = array(
  'data_item_description'=> $test_name_array[$count],
  'data_item_reference'  => $ref_value_array[$count]
  );

 $this->db->insert('data_item',$data_item_array);
 //get the 'data_item_id'
 $data_item_id[] = $this->db->insert_id();
}

Console::log(implode(',', $data_item_id));
```

Comment: Use `implode(',', $myArray);`.  You already seem to know the function, so wondering why the question!

Comment: @vinodadhikary it only gets the index not the value.

Comment: Could you share the exact code you're using? `implode()` is supposed to concatenate the values, not the keys.

Comment: a while ago that doesn't work.. maybe i just need a rest.thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a function called exactly [`implode()`](http://php.net/implode) that will do this for you.
Use it like this:

```
$a = array ( 96, 97, 98, 99, 100,);
print implode(',', $a);
```

Comment: yeah but it only gets the 0,1,2,3,4.

Comment: I don't think that it's the case if your array looks like the one in the question, added code snippet to demonstrate what I'm thinking.

Comment: It's not the case. To get `0,1,2,3,4` you would have to do `implode(array_keys($array))`

Comment: the question is already solved guys. ANSWER : implode(',', array_values($myArray)); btw thanks for answering

Comment: @Nico show us the full code because you are obviously manipulating it somehow before doing implode.